# Can I force modify a file in use by another process (programmatically)?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to use a PowerShell command to programmatically force modify a file in use by another process.  When performed manually - opening the `.txt file`, deleting all contents and saving - it works just fine.  I would like to make a programmatic solution.

My first thoughts were using something like this in PowerShell:

```
cd C:\foobar
remove-item trail.txt.1 -force
```

But this doesnt seem to be allowed even with admin priviledges.  Is there someway to do this without restarting the `explorer.exe` process during the operation?

Comment: Have you tried doing the equivalent of what you're describing instead? `Clear-Content trail.txt.1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen:  this causes the same IO exception as trying to remove the item.